# Pulling Docker containers from Docker hub behind a proxy results in "certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: ssl, docker, proxy

I'm pulling Docker containers from Docker Hub behind an HTTPS Squid proxy that decrypts traffic.

Since I don't have the proxy SSL certificates to trust in my CA root, I'm getting the following SSL error while pulling:
**https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/.../images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

I know that I can append --insecure-registry to private repositories to ignore this issue, but I can't ignore registries hosted on Docker for some reason. I did some analysis on my local DNS server to see which hostnames from Docker were resolving and tried the following:

**--insecure-registry docker.io --insecure-registry registry-origin.docker.io --insecure-registry index.docker.io --insecure-registry auth.docker.io --insecure-registry registry-1.docker.io**

None of these are successfully allowing me to pull from Docker Hub. Is there a way to get this to work correctly?